# laravel 5, form submit redirect to unknown url value

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I just wondering in my project. I have a form that can be access at `localhost/app/esetting/mymail` and this is the code in the view:

```
....
 <form action="{{ url( 'app/esetting/emailautomsave' ) }}" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                         {{ csrf_field() }}
...
<input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

but when I try to click for form submission, I expect it to go to `app/esetting/emailautomsave` and calls it controller which is on my `SettingsController.php`.

```
public function postEmailautomsave(Request $request){
...
}
```

but it redirects to `localhost/app/mymail`? and give me this error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 93: 
Controller method not found.
```

this sounds weird on my end. can anyone have an idea about this? I am sure I have done the right this specially on my `routes.php`

```
Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'app', 'middleware' => 'auth' ], function() {
....
Route::controller('esetting', 'SettingController');
Route::get( 'esetting/mymail', 'SettingController@viewEmailAutom' ); // view for the form to display
....
```

Comment: Not sure if that's just a typo, but your closing form tag is incorrect.

Comment: Also, your url is /esetting/... but you are using Route::controller('setting', ...)

Comment: have you checked your auth middleware ?

Comment: I'm not using Route::controller, I love exactly defining routes to avoid problems of searching which route served by which action.

Comment: add your setting controller code in the question

Answer (score 1):

Just simply define:

```
Route::post('esetting/mymail/emailautomsave', 'SettingController@postEmailautomsave');
```

I know that You'll say: "I've defined Route::controller, so it will look for it atuomatically."

But for me is best to have routes defined exactly.

also if:

> it redirects to localhost/app/mymail? and give me this error:
>
> NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 93:  Controller method
>   not found.

maybe it means that some middleware is redirecting You there?

You can check it by simply doing this:

```
public function postEmailautomsave(Request $request){
  die('test');
  ...
}
```

if it will redirect so it mean that some function was called before and redirect browser to `app/mymail`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Route::controller you need to define you methods according to the route.
E.g.

```php
Route::controller('esetting', 'SettingController');
```

Will look for SettingController@getIndex when you visit http:://yoursite.com/esetting

To reach SettingController@postEmailAutomsave() you would need to go to the route http:://yoursite.com/esetting/emmail/automsave

I have not used Route::controller myself, I got used too (and now prefer) naming them individually.
But this should do the trick.

[Laravel 5.1 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#implicit-controllers)